# Is there one word for "selfless to a fault"

Tags: single-word-requests

What one word describes someone who spends so much time and effort looking after others, they neglect their own needs?

The other question/answers does not address the neglect of one's own needs.

I'll think about a sample sentence.

Comment: Can you write an example sentence with more context where the word or phrase would be used? The following is the strict guideline of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122506/word-to-describe-a-person-who-is-only-wishful-to-help-others-and-cares-little-a